# Microsoft AD - Negative OU= LDAP filter

Tags: active-directory, ldap, filter

I am trying to produce a LDAP Filter for MS AD which filters users based on some OUs (in my case excluding a specific OU but also including does not work):

```
(&(cn=Testuser1)(|(ou:dn:=Included1)(ou:dn:=Included2)))
(&(cn=Testuser1)(!(ou:dn:=Excluded)))
```

does not work. I tested `(ou:dn:=Included1)` which lists the actual "folder" objects (marked with * below) but not the users below that (with the DN containing the ou). I cannot use the search base because it should find multiple:

```
ou=Included1,dc=example,dc=com *
  cn=Testuser1,ou=Included1,dc=example,dc=com +
ou=Included2,dc=example,dc=com
  cn=Testuser1,ou=Included2,dc=example,dc=com +
ou=Excluded,dc=example,dc=com
  cn=Testuser1,ou=Excluded,dc=example,dc=com -
```

In my two example filters above I want to find two Testuser1 entries (marked with +), not three (marked with -).

But it actually matches none. The actual user entries have no other differences in the attributes I can filter on.

What it feels like is that the "`ou:dn:=`" syntax only finds object where the first name component it the desired one, not any...?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632418/ldap-exclude-sub-ou-from-search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The negative OU= component filter seems to not work with Microsoft LDAP since it is a constructed attribute (thanks to @semicolon for the link).

However it works to use the full attribute value like:

```
(&(CN=%u)(!(distinguishedName=CN=%u,OU=Excluded,dc=example,dc=com)))
```